# How to hide monthly active users for an app? Do not want to make this public

Tags: facebook-graph-api

All the Facebook apps seem to show monthly active users. Is there a way to make this private and not public?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this; `monthly_active_users` is a public field of the [application object in the Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/)

e.g. Farmville: http://graph.facebook.com/102452128776?fields=monthly_active_users,name

Comment: Is this still impossible?

Comment: Yes, this field is still public